# Small table covers one whole page

Tags: tables, layout, size

I'm making some final corrections for my Elsevier submission. I have a problem with some tables covering a whole page, although they are small, and I can't manage to fix it. Here is the code.

```
     \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
     \begin{document}
     \begin{frontmatter}

      \begin{table}
            \caption{IoT Applications Overview}
            \label{tab:3}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{p{0.25\columnwidth} p{0.6\columnwidth}}
            \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
            Application Type & Functionality  \\
            \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
                 Environmental 
                     & Smart Water Supply \\
                     & Smart Agriculture \\
                     & Environment Monitoring \\[0.75ex]
                 Healthcare 
                     & Heart Rate Monitoring \\
                     & Blood Pressure Monitoring \\
                     & Glucometer Monitoring \\
                     & Real-Time Location of Medical Equipment \\[0.75ex]
                 Social 
                     & Smart Homes \\
                     & Smart Surveillance \\
                     & Smart Mobility \\
                     & Smart Social Interactions \\
                     & Smart Shopping \\[0.75ex]
                 \raggedright
                 Energy Management & Smart Grid \\[0.75ex]
                 Industry 4.0 
                     & Automated Machinery \\
                     & Smart Manufacturing \\[0.75ex]
                 Industry 5.0 
                     & Synergy of Human and A.I. \\
            \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of information. Updated the code with document class.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Please make your code snippet minimally compilable. E.g., do tell us exactly how the `\documentclass` command is used, and please tell us how the `table` environment is called.

Comment: As far as I see, your table occupy about 40% of page. What is actually your problem?

Comment: I am working on the Elsevier template, and once compiled the table covers one page on its own, not allowing any text to fill the page

Comment: Sorry, with your document example we cant reproduce your problem. It may help, if you add placement option to the `table`, for example `\begin{table}[ht]` or `\begin{table}[!ht]`.

Comment: naturally in the example you posted the table takes a whole page as there is no other text in the document, what help can anyone give with such an example?

Comment: See the not enough upvoted question [about how to influence the position of floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/) and do not forget that some floats of journal classes could have a different default behavior (for instance, to print each table and figure  in a different page alone or avoid some placement options) that you should not try to change (no idea if this could be the case).

Comment: Some pubishers require all floats to be at the end of the article (built in endfloat).  Nothing you can or should do about that.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that the table in question is not only printed on a page by itself, but is likely also at the very end of the document. To fix this situation, it should suffice to replace `\begin{table}` with `\begin{table}[ht!]`.

Incidentally, I would also expend some effort to spruce up the look of the table, mostly in order to improve the odds that your readers will actually bother to look at it and absorb its information.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,calc}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

     \begin{table}[ht!]
           \caption{IoT Applications Overview\strut}
           \label{tab:3}
           \centering
           \begin{tabular}{@{} P{\widthof{Application Type}} l @{}}
           \toprule
           Application Type & Functionality  \\
           \midrule
               Environmental 
                  & Smart Water Supply \\
                  & Smart Agriculture \\
                  & Environment Monitoring \\ \addlinespace
               Healthcare 
                  & Heart Rate Monitoring \\
                  & Blood Pressure Monitoring \\
                  & Glucometer Monitoring \\
                  & Real-Time Location of Medical Equipment \\ \addlinespace
               Social 
                  & Smart Homes \\
                  & Smart Surveillance \\
                  & Smart Mobility \\
                  & Smart Social Interactions \\
                  & Smart Shopping \\ \addlinespace
               Energy Management 
                  & Smart Grid \\ \addlinespace
               Industry 4.0 
                  & Automated Machinery \\
                  & Smart Manufacturing \\ \addlinespace
               Industry 5.0 
                  & Synergy of Human and AI \\
           \bottomrule
           \end{tabular}
     \end{table}

\end{document}
```